# Multiplication matrix and store sram or sdram

Tags: matrix, verilog, multiplication

I'm starting a project where I multiply matrices and synthesize it in FPGA / Changes DE2.
As I'm starting, I would like guidance on how to operate store this value in memory.
What I want to do is [C] = [A] * [B].
Note: The values ​​of [A], [B] and [C] are automatically stored in SRAM or SDRAM?
When I read the question: [Verilog For Loop For Array Multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037762/verilog-for-loop-for-array-multiplication) became clearer how to operate, but I can not see how to manage it to be entered into memory.
Anyone have some code that I can adapt to read and write to memory?
I am following this path would be right?

Edit:

I have this code for matrix 4x4 multiplication. Can you tell me if this code is right? I try run, but the C value is not save into memory.

```
module rams(
input clk,
  //  SRAM Interface
  inout  [15:0] SRAM_DQ,   // SRAM Data bus 16 Bits
  output [17:0] SRAM_ADDR, // SRAM Address bus 18 Bits
  output SRAM_UB_N,        // SRAM High-byte Data Mask
  output SRAM_LB_N,        // SRAM Low-byte Data Mask 
  output SRAM_WE_N,    // SRAM Write Enable
  output SRAM_CE_N,        // SRAM Chip Enable
  output SRAM_OE_N        // SRAM Output Enable
);

parameter mat_size = 4;  // change the size of the matrices here.
reg [7:0] A_mat [0:mat_size*mat_size-1];
reg [7:0] B_mat [0:mat_size*mat_size-1];


wire [15:0] mem_in;
reg [17:0] mem_address;

wire [7:0] A,B;
wire [7:0] C;
wire [19:0] A_addr,B_addr,C_addr;
reg reset;
wire start;
reg [9:0] Cr,Cc;

assign SRAM_ADDR = mem_address;
assign SRAM_UB_N = 1'b0;        // SRAM High-byte Data Mask
assign SRAM_LB_N = 1'b0;        // SRAM Low-byte Data Mask 
assign SRAM_CE_N = 1'b0;        // SRAM Chip Enable
assign SRAM_OE_N = 1'b0;        // SRAM Output Enable

reg [2:0] state;
parameter idle=0, read_A=1, read_B=2, start_process=3,do_nothing = 4;;

assign SRAM_WE_N = (valid_output ? 1'b0 : 1'b1);
assign start = !(valid_output | reset);//(valid_output ? 1'b0 : 1'b1);
assign SRAM_DQ = (valid_output ? mem_in : 16'hzzzz);

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    mat_mult uut (
        .clk(clk), 
        .reset(reset), 
        .start(start),
        .A_addr(A_addr), 
        .B_addr(B_addr), 
        .C_addr(C_addr), 
        .A(A), 
        .B(B), 
        .mat_size(mat_size), 
        .C(C), 
        .valid_output(valid_output)
    );

assign mem_in = {4'h00,C};

initial begin
    state = idle;
end     

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    case (state)
        idle :
            begin
                mem_address <= 16'h0000;
                state = read_A;
                reset <= 1'b1;
            end
        read_A :    
            begin
                A_mat[mem_address] <= SRAM_DQ;
                if(mem_address < mat_size*mat_size) begin
                    state = read_A;
                    mem_address <= mem_address + 1;
                end else begin
                    state = read_B;
                end 
            end
        read_B :    
            begin
                B_mat[mem_address-(mat_size*mat_size)] <= SRAM_DQ;
                if(mem_address < 2*mat_size*mat_size) begin
                    state = read_B;
                    mem_address <= mem_address + 1;
                end else begin
                    state = start_process;
                    reset <= 1'b0;
                end 
            end 
        start_process : 
            begin
                state = start_process;
                mem_address <= 2*mat_size*mat_size + C_addr;
                if(C_addr == mat_size*mat_size-1) begin 
                    state = do_nothing;
                end else begin
                    reset <= 1'b0;
                end
            end     
        do_nothing : 
            if(valid_output) begin
                reset <= 1'b1;
            end 
    endcase

end

assign A = A_mat[A_addr];
assign B = B_mat[B_addr];

endmodule
```

I load value A and B together, format hex 16. I into values with DE_Control Altera, becouse i don't know how to do this using your code for load.
And module for multiply is:

```
module mat_mult(
    input clk,
    input reset,
     input start,
    output [19:0] A_addr,
    output [19:0] B_addr,
    output [19:0] C_addr,
    input [7:0] A,
    input [7:0] B,
     input [9:0] mat_size,
    output [7:0] C,
     output valid_output
    );

reg [9:0] Ar,Br,Bc,Cr,Cc;
reg [7:0] C_res;
reg v;

always @ (posedge clk or posedge reset)
    if (reset) begin
        Ar <= 10'b0000000000;
        Br <= 10'b0000000000;
        Bc <= 10'b0000000000;
        Cr <= 10'b0000000000;
        Cc <= 10'b0000000000;
        C_res <= 8'h00;
        v <= 1'b0;
    end else begin
        if (start) begin
            if (Br == mat_size-1) begin
                Br <= 10'b0000000000;
                if (Bc == mat_size-1) begin
                    Bc <= 10'b0000000000;
                    if (Ar == mat_size-1) begin
                        Ar <= 10'b0000000000;
                    end else begin
                        Ar <= Ar + 1;
                    end
                end else begin
                    Bc <= Bc + 1;
                end
                v <= 1'b1;
            end else begin
                Br <= Br + 1;
            end
            C_res <= C_res + A*B;
        end else begin
            C_res <= 8'h00;
            v <= 1'b0;
        end 
    end 

assign A_addr = (Ar * mat_size) + Br;
assign B_addr = (Br * mat_size) + Bc;
assign C_addr = (Ar * mat_size) + Bc;
assign C = C_res;
assign valid_output = v;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with memory, just remember that it's just a mapping between addresses and bytes. So if you think of a matrix (I'll assume 4x4 of 32-bit floats here for simplicity), then what you really have is just 16 floating point 32-bit numbers.

The way you store these in memory will be different if you intend to store them in on-chip memory (SRAM cells integrated into the FPGA die), or off chip, into some DDR type of memory.

To store them on chip is easier to work with, in this case in verilog you just declare an array, and then read and write from it one element at a time. Your synthesizer will infer this as a RAM provided that your FPGA has available ram cells of the right size available.

```
module matrixmem;

input clk;
input [3:0] addr;
input [31:0] data_in;
output [31:0] data_out;
input write;
input read;

reg [31:0] mem [0:15]; //16 32-bit elements, enough to store one 4x4 array.

always @(posedge clk) begin
   if(write)
       mem[addr] <= data_in;
   else if (read)
       data_out <= mem[addr];
end
```

Then via this module you can pull out the elements of the array one at a time, by changing the address, where the address represents which element of the matrix you want to pull.

If you want to store these off chip it's a bit more complicated, as you'll need to implement a DDR controller or leverage some IP that comes with your FPGA in order to communicate with external ram. But essentially it works the same way, as each element of a matrix will be stored in a certain address.

Answer (score 0):

one more precaution that you must always bear in mind is that when declaring an always block it is advisable to declare the output port as reg type if it is a sequential block.

as for the solution here if we want to use data_out for storing the value, we need to declare it as reg type. else it is fine.